# subtracting trig

Tags: trigonometry

I can't seem to get passed this hurdle, and I just literally have no idea where to start from.

$$2\cos^2(2x) - 2\sin^2(2x) = \text{ ?}$$

I'm being told it's $2\cos(4x)$, but I have no clue how to they got there. If someone could give me a head start (not the answer) on what trig identity to use, I'd be really grateful. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Michael. Not used to this type of writing yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\cos2A=\cos^{2}A-\sin^{2}A$$
To say any more would be writing down the answer.

Comment: I did not know about that trig identity >_< Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The equation you want to make use of is:

$$\cos(2x) = \cos^2x-\sin^2x.$$

This can be derived from the relation

$$\cos(x\pm y) = \cos x\cos y \mp \sin x\sin y$$

by setting $y = x$.

Comment: That actually makes sense. Thanks for the added detail!

Comment: You're very welcome!